# How to SELECT next available award from available awards

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am in process of designing my database.

It's a simple online course, which users can earn points by achieving certain goals. For instance, if a user passes a quiz with score over 90, then 50 'iq' points are awarded to student.

My specific question here is, How would I find out the NEXT available award, and how many points are needed to obtain award.

So here is my idea of the tables (very truncated here for brevity of course):

**Users table**

```
id
name
points_balance
```

**Awards table**
This table holds all available awards.

```
id
award_name
points
award_sql
```

The award_sql column holds a sql statement to run to find out if the user is eligible for this award. For example, I could add a sql statement here to check to see if the user logged in three consecutive days. If true, user eligible for this award.

**User_awards**
Holds the awards a user already obtained

```
id
user_id
award_id
date_awarded
```

So the ideal query would do the following:

1. Check to see if the user qualifies for the award and doesn't already have it
2. Based on the list returned above, I need to know which which award is CLOSEST in points.

**Schema Is Rough Draft**
The table structure above is just my first draft.

**I am new to writing SQL**

If there is a better way to design my tables, I'd love to hear your suggestion.

Thank you for looking. I have looked into using the MIN function, but that's kinda above my skill set right now.

Comment: It would be good if you could construct your award_sql into a standard set of rules, otherwise you are going to have to use dynamic sql which is a lot more ugly. If you do that, then your query will be a combination of your checking logic, plus the row_number() function to get the first award>points_balance. If you were to post your sample award_sql clauses then we might be able to suggest how to code it.

Comment: ORDER BY and LIMIT seems like it would suffice (unless multiple awards share the same points score)

Comment: Well, I don't have my award clause SQL written yet. I'm sort of in design phase. I had a few in mind, however. 3 consecutive days logged in (login_history table) , 90 percent or better on quiz (quiz_results table) , user sent a referral to friend (referral table), completed a lesson (student_progress table), user liked us on Facebook (social table), etc.  So to come up with a rule set to cover things like that...wow I wouldn't even know where to begin. That's why I thought sql column would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would design my Awards tables as below:
Instead of the column "award_sql" in Awards table it would be better to have something like "award_status". This column will have a value "y" or "n" based on the user qualifying for the award. 
In this design awards.award_status gets populated or loaded after login_history,quiz_results,referral_table and the remaining dependent tables are loaded. Use the award clause SQL to populate award_status column.

Comment: Ohhhh I think I see what you mean. You suggest at the time of the student qualifying for an award ( for instance, when the log in, check right then and there to see if it's their third straight day, if so the award is available), or as soon as they send referral, make award available right then and there.  Am I understanding that? Because if so, THAT approach would surely be easier. I do like it. In this approach, I would need to add some methods to my model (MVC) but so what, right? I'm hoping I understood you correctly, and there is nothing fundamentally wrong with the above approach.Thx!!!